# I want Azure Pipeline to build equally named branch as the triggering pipeline has just built

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Problem**

I have two repositories `A` and `B` in one project, each with their own pipeline `A-CI` and `B-CI`. The repos are Azure Repos Git (so not external ones). I got it working to trigger pipeline `B-CI` whenever `A-CI` has completed. If `A-CI` got triggered by a commit to branch `develop`, then `B-CI` is triggered to build `master` although `B` also has a `develop` branch.
I want to build a new release of `B` for the dev environment, when a new dev version of `A` has been built.

Is it possible to let a pipeline-resource trigger the `B-CI` pipeline to build the branch with the same name as the branch which was just built by the pipeline-resource? It would be fine for me if it would fallback to `master` in case a matching branch is not available in `B`.

This scenario is working however if `A-C` and `B-CI` would both refer to different pipeline yamls of the **same** repository.

**Pipeline YAMLs**

A-CI

```yaml
trigger:
- '*'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      name: 'MyBuildPool'
    steps:
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "Building A"
```

B-CI

```yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: Pipeline_A
      source: 'A-CI'
      trigger:
        branches:
          - master
          - develop
          - feature/*

trigger: 
- '*'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      name: MyBuildPool
    steps:
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host $(Build.SourceBranch) # is always refs/heads/master
          Write-Host $(Build.Reason) # is ResourceTrigger
```

**Background Info**

The main idea behind that is, that `A` contains the IaC project and whenever the infrastructure of the project changes, then all apps should be deployed, too.
I do not want to put the IaC into the app repo because we have multiple apps, so I would have to split the IaC code into several chunks.
And then I would probably still have the same problem because some resources, like Azure KeyVault, are shared among the apps so `A` would still include the common stuff used by all apps and changes to it would require re-deployments of all apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a nicely working workaround as the built-in pipeline-triggers are not addressing our specific problem (though I can't say if we have an odd approach and there are better ways).

What I am doing now it to use the [Azure CLI DevOps extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension) based on this [docs entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/azure-devops-cli-in-yaml?view=azure-devops) and trigger the pipelines manually.

**Pipeline YAMLs**

A-CI

```yaml
trigger:
- '*'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build something and create a pipeline artifact
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      name: 'MyBuildPool'
    steps:
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "Building A"
      # steps to publish artifact omitted

- stage: TriggerAppPipelines
  displayName: Trigger App Pipeline
  jobs:
  - job: TriggerAppPipelinesJob
    displayName: Trigger App Pipeline
    steps:
    - bash: az extension list | grep azure-devops
      displayName: 'Ensure Azure CLI DevOps extension is installed'
    - bash: |
        echo ${AZURE_DEVOPS_CLI_PAT} | az devops login
        az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg project="MyProject" --use-git-aliases true
      displayName: 'Login Azure CLI'
      env:
        AZURE_DEVOPS_CLI_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
    # By passing the build Id of this A-CI run, I can use that in B-CI to download the matching artifact of A-CI.
    # If there is no matching branch, then the command fails. 
    - bash: |
        az pipelines run --branch $(Build.SourceBranch) --name "B-CI" --variables a_Version="$(Build.BuildId)" -o none
      displayName: 'Trigger pipeline'
```

B-CI

```yaml
trigger: 
- '*'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      name: MyBuildPool
    steps:
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host $(Build.SourceBranch) # is same as the the triggering A-CI branch
          Write-Host $(Build.Reason) # B-CI is triggered manually but the user is Project Collection Build Service, so automated runs can be distinguished
```

As B-CI is triggered manually now, there is no need for a resource node anymore.

Comment: What user does this process run as? I am trying to do this between two projects (in the same ADO org) and I get what looks like a permissions error. As far as I can see, this is running as the "ADO system user" so not something you can give permission to...

Answer (score 1):

Please check [pipeline triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-triggers):

*If the triggering pipeline and the triggered pipeline use the same repository, then both the pipelines will run using the same commit when one triggers the other. This is helpful if your first pipeline builds the code, and the second pipeline tests it.*

**However, if the two pipelines use different repositories, then the triggered pipeline will use the latest version of the code from its default branch.**

In this case, since `master` if the default branch of your `B-CI`, `$(Build.SourceBranch)` is always `refs/heads/master`.

**As a workaround:**

You can create a new yaml pipeline for repository `B`. You can use similar content of the yaml file for B-CI. And you only need to change something in it to:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: Pipeline_A
      source: 'A-CI'
      trigger:
        branches:
          - develop
```

When we create the new yaml file, it's always placed in master branch. For me, I created a file with same name in dev branch, and copy the same content in it. Then i delete the new yaml file in master branch, now when dev of A-CI pipeline is built, dev of B repos will be used.

Comment: Tanks for pointing me to the docs part where this behavior is explained.  
Does your workaround mean, that it is not possible to have every matching branch built upon builds of A-CI?  
We use git flow as our branch strategy, so release/* branches, hotfix/*, develop and master should be built automatically, too.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have developed another approach using azure cli (see my answer) that solves our problem.
But I just wonder if our approach is to "special" and normally you would do it different. What we want to achieve is a fully automated rollout of infrastructure as code and all apps running in it.

Comment: The funny thing is that on the page describing pipeline resources, they specifically call out that it can already do this, but not HOW. " For instance, there is no way to trigger a pipeline on the same branch as that of the triggering pipeline using build completion triggers." (talking about the old way with build completion triggers vs the resources way)